# Primality proof algorithms for extremely large integers of no specific form

Tags: algorithm, primes, memory-efficient, primality-test

I am looking for an algorithm that would make it possible to prove *any* large number for primality.  By large number, I mean numbers with at least 100,000,000 decimal digits in them and which cannot be expressed with simple formulas like Mersenne primes, etc.

Here are my requirements:

1- it must be completely correct

2- it must be runnable on a basic home computer

3- It must complete it's course within a few weeks or months.

My memory limitation is 8 GB of ram (I can set my options on how much cache is available) on a dedicated machine with a 1tb hard drive.  I will be considering numbers one at a time over the course of several months.

Edit1: I am well aware of the fact that this is a difficult arena to compete in, if not nearly impossible using current methods.  I'm not using current methods, and I need a way of proving my methods correct for very large numbers.

Edit2: Part of the reason why I need a non-probabilistic method is because this will be an attempt at an EFF award, and, succeeding there, at a second EFF award.  If my methods are correct (and that's one honking IF), I should be able to do all that with my notebook PC.

Comment: The standard argument for using something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29 instead of a more complex but theoretically more certain proof is that if you run a probabalistic primality test often enough the chance of the probabalistic test failing because it picked bad random numbers is smaller than the chance of a more complex prime proof algorithm failing because of a transient computer failure. Note that at least some probabalistic prime proofs have their declared worst case failure probs for ALL primes.

Comment: For most purposes, probabilistic methods are fine.  In my case, I am making an attempt at EFF awards, and that requires sure proof with no leeway for probability.  Otherwise, I would take that approach right now.

Comment: Note that with numbers of that magnitude, an `O((log n)^3)` algorithm would already run several million years. Until a major breakthrough in primality proving is made, you won't be able to prove such numbers prime within your lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are looking for a algorithm which is:

- deterministic
- fairly fast
- with a fairly reasonable memory footprint

I'm not sure about the last part, since I never tried to implement it (yet), but I know that the primality problem was solved for general numbers. In other words, you can determine if a number is prime or not, with 100% certainty, regardless of the form. You should take a look at the [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) which is the first known algorithm that solves this problem.

Like you said, it may take a while to run, but it will eventually finish with a certain answer. The complexity of the optimized version is O((log n)^7.5 (log n is proportional with the number of digits of n).

However, since this runtime is pretty large and you want to test for a lot of numbers, you should consider filtering such numbers with a faster, non-deterministic algorithm first. In other words, I would try to run the [Miller-Rabin test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin) for a few numbers (a=2,3,5,7,... - the first ten primes should be enough, but even if you really want a better accuracy, you probably shouldn't go beyond 50 primes). The probability that the tested number is a false-prime after k Miller-Rabin tests is less than 1/4^k if I remember correctly. In other words, you can run a small number of tests (not to mention these tests are very fast) and be very confident if the number is prime (if any of these tests fail, the number is definitely NOT prime). After all the MR tests pass, run the AKS algorithm on the tested number just to make sure (as you can see on the MR wikipedia page, the smallest false positive after doing even a few tests increases at a very fast rate).

Comment: Just to add a note, since I saw mcdowella mentioned the method in java's BigInteger. Guessing from the certainty of the algorithm used by that method, I suppose it uses the Solovay-Strassen primality test, which is weaker than Miller-Rabin (their complexity is about the same, so I would personally go for the more accurate one, even if I had to implement it myself).

Comment: This helps; I will be investigating these suggestions for a while before checking this as answered.